# locate command for searching exact filename only

Tags: command-line

Whenever I use the `locate` command it shows me all the possible wrap around results; if I am searching for `xyz.c`, and use `locate xyz.c`  I get

```
/../../../abc_xyz.c
  /../../../xyzabc_gvdvd.c
  /../../../abcxyz.c
 /../../../xyz.c
```

what to do if I want exactly `xyz.c` only ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From `man locate`

```
EXAMPLES
   To search for a file named exactly NAME (not *NAME*), use
          locate -b '\NAME'
   Because \ is a globbing character, this disables the implicit  replace‐
   ment of NAME by *NAME*.
```

Therefore...

```
locate -b '\xyz.c'
```

Comment: This seems not to work for `plocate` which apparently doesn't consider \ a globbing character. You could use `[N]AME` instead, which does work.

Comment: Note to self: don't skim read this and put `\b`, even though that is a closely related concept!

Comment: It does not to work for me as expected as it will get also `xyz.cpp-or-some-other-extension` if exists ( it behaves as the ` \ ` would remove only the first `*` from `*NAME*` ). What works for me as expected is [x]yz.c as mentioned by @BeeOnRope. What raises the question: why does `[N]AME` work?

Comment: What also works (tested using plocate/updatedb 1.1.15) is appropriate regular expression: `locate --regex /xyz.c$`

Comment: @Claudio - `[N]AME` works because the `[]` is a globbing construct, so it disables the implicit leading and trailing `*`, yet still only matches `NAME` since `[N]` only matches `N`.